# Expected value of a function of random variables

Tags: probability

Is the following true for two, not necessarily independent random variables?

$E\left[g(x,y)\right]=\iint g(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy$, where $f(x,y)$ is the joint pdf and $g(x,y)$ is any function with range $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, as long as $g$ is reasonably nice enough (for example bounded and continuous would work), and $f$ does, in fact, exist.